# Performance due to multiple frameworks in ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, performance, ipad

I have added jquery, jquerymobile, less.js, raphel.js and google maps api in my web app. Will it lead to any performance drawbacks while user use it in ipads / iphone.

won't they occupy more memory?

Comment: Of course, they will occupy some memory. Of course, the app will perform slower with those frameworks than without them. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Of course they occupy more memory than if you'd not include not them!? But it doesn't matter as long as you don't see any *real* performance issues

Comment: i don't feel any performance issues. but i need to know how others are doing. in today's app world we can not omit jquery. are you all use any external frameworks in ipad / iphone apps.